# QGIS integration with Geomesa OR GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, qgis, geomesa

I am using GeoMesa 2.3.1. I want to connect my Geomesa AWS EMR cluster from QGIS-3.4 version. While investigating, I found (http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/geomesa/), where the blog talked about how to use QGIS for Geomesa via GeoServer.

Following this blog, when I tried on installed Geoserver plugins (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/geoserverexplorer/) on QGIS-3.4.11-Madeira, then I found the plugin is not compatible with QGIS 3.4.11. This plugin is designed for Plugin designed for QGIS 2.14 - 2.99.

Is there any other way to connect QGIS with Geomesa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you need the QGIS GeoServer plugin - you should be able to connect to GeoServer using WFS or WMS as detailed in the QGIS [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/ogc_client_support.html).

Comment: Do you have any document which talks about what should be the Geoserver and QGIS WMS configuration?